# Local images not showing in Ionic

Tags: android, ios, image, ionic-framework, build

I know tht this question have been asked several times, and I have tried all solutions that I can find on the Internet without success so I'm trying here again to see if I have missed something.

I'm building an hybrid app using Ionic. I have a local image that I want to be able to show even if the user starts the app without an Internet connection or loses the connection while going through the app. Therefore I want to have the image locally.

This is my tag for getting the image: `<img class="track-image-left" src="images/track.png" />`. The image is located in www/images after Ionic has built the app.

I have tried ionic emulate android --lc and viewing the console in Chrome gives me the following: `GET file:///android_asset/www/images/track.png net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`. The only thing I can find looks funny is that Ionic adds some string to the filename when building, so the image file name in the actual folder looks like `track.516c558c.png`. Can this be the problem?

Otherwise, does anyone know what the problem might be?

Note that the problem occurs both in Android and iOS.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was that I use grunt to build the app before emulating with ionic. Grunt did the file name change, but it was done so late in the build process (running `grunt build --force && ionic emulate android --lc` that it looked like ionic was doing the file name change, not grunt.

Therefore, I instead did this:

```
.track-image-left {
  background: url('../images/train-track.png') no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  display:inline-block;
  float: left;
  height: 20px;
  width: 40px;
  margin-top: 40%;
}

.track-image-right {
  background: url('../images/train-track.png') no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  display:inline-block;
  float: right;
  height: 20px;
  width: 40px;
  margin-top: 40%;

  -moz-transform: scaleX(-1);
  -o-transform: scaleX(-1);
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
  transform: scaleX(-1);
  filter: FlipH;
  -ms-filter: "FlipH";
}

<div class="track-image-left"></div>
<div class="track-image-right"></div>
```

Which worked fine.